Connection timed out error in mlcp export
mlcp export command is giving timed out error after completion of 33% while exporting jsons. I have increased the timeouts in the xdbc server configurations, but still not able to export complete collection.
Error message:

ERROR mapreduce.MarkLogicRecordReader: RequestException:Connection timed out: connect

mlcp command:
mlcp.bat EXPORT -host hostname -port portNumber -username admin -password admin -mode local -output_file_path "C:\\exportSample" -collection_filter "sampleTest"
xdbc server time out configurations:

request timeout: 300 secs
keep alive timeout: 300 secs
session timeout: 3600 secs

Versions:

Marklogic server: 10
mlcp: 11 & 9 (same error in both the versions)


What are the appserver threads configured for? Maybe try explicitly setting MLCP threads to 1 -thread_count 1 and then if successful, increasing to something that is less than the appserver threads and still runs without connection timeout.
